# Tests are not stable, fail from time to time

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I've got some troubles with UFT since my test fails from time to time and I can't figure out why. My test is quite simple, on my first page I've got a "select" where I choose a user and a button to connect. Then I verify wich tabs are shown (it depends on the user) and disconnect.

My test call 4 external actions:

Login

```
Browser("home").Page("home").WebList("user").Select Parameter("user")
Browser("home").Page("home").WebButton("connect").Click
```

Tab verification

```
If( Browser("home").Page("homepage").Link("tab1").Exist = False ) Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Tab1", "Tab1 not found"
    ExitTest
End If

If( Browser("home").Page("homepage").Link("tab2").Exist = False ) Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Tab2", "Tab2 not found"
    ExitTest
End If

If( Browser("home").Page("homepage").Link("tab3").Exist = False ) Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Tab3", "Tab3 not found"
    ExitTest
End If
```

Or, depending on user

```
If( Browser("home").Page("homepage").Link("tab1").Exist = False ) Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Tab1", "Tab1 not found"
    ExitTest
End If

If( Browser("home").Page("homepage").Link("tab2").Exist ) Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Tab2", "Tab2 shouldn't be display for this user"
    ExitTest
End If

If( Browser("home").Page("homepage").Link("tab3").Exist = False ) Then
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Tab3", "Tab3 not found"
    ExitTest
End If
```

Logout

```
Browser("home").Page("homepage").Link("disconnect").Click
```

The test who call those 4 external actions runs for my 10 users and 3 browsers (ie, firefox and chrome). Yesterday I launched this test 10 times and only one test fails for one profil on one browser "impossible to identify object "user" (WebList)".

So is there something wrong with my code, and if so why it only fails from time to time? Or is there a stability issue with uft?

Thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the code of the WebList

```
<form>
    <p>
        <select name="user" id="user">
            <option th:each="user : ${users}" th:value="${user.id}" th:text="${user.name}">Default</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="connect" value="connect" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't sound like your code or UFT at fault.  Seems likely that there's some property of the WebList object "user" that was different for the failed run which meant that UFT couldn't find it.  Try to reproduce the error and if you do, note the parameters in use as well as verify the various properties revealed by the Object Spy.  You will need to compare those properties to the learned ones in the Object Repository to see what's different.

Comment: I agree with Dave.  What I would do is to add an exist check at the beginning... if not Browser("home").Page("home").WebList("user").exist then stop the script, leave it on the screen, and use GuiSpy to check all of it's attributes to see why it isn't being found by the test object called "user".  Odds are good that you can fix this by improving the test object in the OR.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will launch again some tests and watch the WebList when it fails

Comment: Are you making sure that only browser is open at a time? If the object properties are the same, then I would suspect that more than one browsers are opened and that's causing your script to fail.

Comment: The list of users is dynamicaly created and not sorted so the innerhtml, innertext, outerhtml, outertext, selection and value are almost always different but they are not in the "description property" of the object (so I don't know if there is a test on those parameters). Yes I've got chrome always open during test and ie with alm open, do you think it could be the reason? I will try again with only one browser open at a time. thanks again

Comment: Try to debug the code, pause at that step and check the properties of WebList.

Comment: I would suggest you give some examples (screenshot better) of the `WebList`. And describe how it is changing dynamically.

Comment: Sorry haven't seen your answer before. In the app, the WebList get the users in the database, so it's always the same users but not always in the same order (I will try to fix that). After some discussions with an expert in the company, he think that the problem may come from my multiple browsers, not from the weblist itself. I will try to fix the WebList (just in case) and I'm trying to do a function to close all my tabs and browsers but it takes a lot of time, uft is really really slow ( +-20 minutes for the same test as the one in my post). Thanks everyone

Comment: A little update, i fixed the weblist, it's always the same, I sorted the users. I launched again some tests with all my others browsers closed, and after some tests, one crashed with the same message "impossible to identify object "user" (WebList)". I tried to watch his properties but the object spy can't identify any object in the page (only a window class object named "Mozilla Firefox") but if I open the app in another tab, all my objects are detected